# Create vertex on a desired part of an edge

Tags: modeling

[image]

Ctrl + R creates vertex exactly between two vertices of an edge but I want it in the place where I click, that is any part of an edge where I click. I wanted to know if there is any such feature available in blender. This will just increase my modeling speed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's true that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> works a bit different for single edge like this other than loop cutting on faces, since it is not designed for that. However, you can select that new vertex then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to slide it along the edge.

Furthermore, a [new coming feature](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/05/08/blender-development-feature-rip-edge-tool/) may benefit such workflow. Just FYI.

Answer (score 25):

### Technique #1: Create a vertex on a desired part of an edge

This solution is based on the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36655/why-does-a-vertex-not-become-part-of-the-edge-it-was-snapped-to).

1. Select the edge
2. Press <kbd>W</kbd>, and select Subdivide
3. Select the new vertex
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
5. Slide the vertex along the edge (the proposed vertex location will snap to the grid), and press <kbd>LMB</kbd> to place the vertex permanently
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while sliding to avoid snapping to the grid

---

### Technique #2: Create a vertex and edge at the same time

NOTE: This technique does not attach the new vertex to the edge. The only way to do this is to drag the new vertex to a vertex created on the desire edge using Technique #1.

Select an existing vertex

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> away from the selected vertex to create a new vertex

[image]

In the 3D Viewport, check to ensure that:

- **Snap During Transform** (magnet icon) is turned **on**
- **Type of Element to Snap** to is set to **Edge**
- **Which Part to Snap Onto Target** is set to **Closest**

[image]

<kbd>RMB</kbd> to drag the vertex to snap to the desired edge (The dragged vertex should have a circle around it to indicate it will snap to the edge). Release the <kbd>RMB</kbd>, and <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm the placement.

[image]

Comment: I think this answer is nicer, because ctrl+R starts to place magenta loop selection circles in the UI and is not as intuitive as the answer you have provided. Victor's answer below is effectively the same, but also nice. Having said that, I've noticed that the vertex isn't actually attached to the edge, when I move the face.

Comment: Thanks @GilesDMiddleton. I didn't realise the shortcoming of my method. I have done a little research, and added Technique #1, which seems to answer the question better. I left the original answer as Technique #2, just in case it is useful in some cases.

Comment: @MechtEngineer I generally follow up Technique #2 by deleting the original edge, selecting the two old vertices and the one new one and pressing F to create two new edges.

Answer (score 7):

You could select the new vertex and use [*Vertex Slide*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Vertices) to change its location on the edge 
<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

Another option would be to extrude vertices: with a single vertex is selected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LMB</kbd> creates a new vertex at the position of the mouse cursor and connects the vertices by a new edge.

Answer (score 3):

For edges connected to a face you can use the Knife tool to place a vertex anywhere you want. If you only want one new vertex to be created then just click and drag through only one edge with the knife tool.

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 3.0+, A very simple way to make a vertex on a line is to:

1. Select the two points you want to add the vertex between
2. Right Click and then Subdivide

You should now have a new vertex between the two points. You can then shift this vertex around to your desired spot on the edge.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and all. But there is a much easier way of doing it. Just Extrude one Vertex from one of the Vertex of the Edge you want, select the snap to Edge and slide the Vertex through the Edge you want like a knife in butter to where you want it to be. Works like a glove.

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude from the current vertex selected. You can do this repeatedly to create a long chain.

Comment: wouldn't this end up with edges that you don't want, and then are doubled up?

Comment: Well I use "remove doubles" for that. But you can also create a Vertex with CTRL + LMouse and grab it with G with the Snap to Edge selected and pull it to your desired edge. That ends the double edge problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select the edge you want the vertex at the middle of, right click, and select Subdivide. It will be directly in the middle of the edge. From there you can slide if you need it at a different position other than 50% along the edge length.

Though not quite as easy as using it on an edge, Subdivide is also available in Vertex Select mode. You can select the vertexes as well and then use it, but note that they need to have an edge directly connecting them together. If you first need that, select the two unconnected verts and use Join (J key), which will make an edge, then you can use Subdivide.