# Add a new edge snapping to a vertex and with an angle constraint?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

How would you add a horizontal line without interference to the other edge?

As shown on the image,

[image]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/create-vertex-on-a-desired-part-of-an-edge

Comment: The thing is that I want to create annother edge, that is starting from the existing vertex that would be conected to the other edge, but the new created edge to be horisontal and the right edge to remain the same - as shown on the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In edit mode press <kbd>K</kbd>, that will start the knife tool. Simply <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> click on the vertex you want the cut to start from, and left click again on the other edge. Snapping for the cut is enabled by default. If you want the new edge to be straight then activate *angle constrain* by pressing <kbd>C</kbd>.  Once you like how the new cut is press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the cut and exit the knife tool.
If you look at the 3d view header, you will see all the options for the knife tool and what button to press.
<sub>(click on image for full size)</sub>

[image]