# Why does a vertex not become part of the edge it was snapped to?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I have tried for tinyCAD, Dynamic Space Bar, Intersect Tool and EdgeTools, Automerge and other stock options, but if I create a *new* vertex (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and constrain it to an axis and I **snap it on another edge**, it ***does not merge together and become a lovely piece with that edge***. 
Besides, I have a small space to snap the Vertex *near to* Edge, but not **on** the edge. And I still couldn't figure out how I to merge the Vertex with the Edge *afterwards*.

[image]

But besides that I really like Blender so far and a lot of things are really well thought out and so I think it is me who is wrong.

Comment: did you try ALT + M in edit mode with the selected vertices?

Comment: yes, but ALT + M of vertices with certain edges makes the the mesh collapse sometimes and acts weird

Comment: Why do you *duplicate* vertice? It's much easier to *extrude* it, because in that case it will be a part of the mesh, while if duplicated - only as a standalone one, not involved in anything. More than that, if merging duplicated, you should take into account what do you merge with

Comment: hm, I don't really understand why duplicating shall be worse, but,yeah, seems like extrude is much easier xDD

Comment: Duplicating isn't worse; it provides you (in this case) with an additional step which is worth doing only if it's needed. And I don't see any reasons why it's really needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to merge this vertex with the edge you have to have another vertex as a part of the edge, to do so, select the edge and by pressing the <kbd>W</kbd> key subdivide it once then you can slide the vertex where you want by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, and now you can merge this vertex with the other vertices.

Comment: hm, well that works. does it make a difference using subdivide over loopcut and slide?  strange though, why isn't snapping made similar to CAD programs, maybe I should look for a proper CAD addon..

Comment: No it doesn't really make any difference as long as you have a vertex which is part of the mesh

Comment: still it does not make absolutely now in any way any sense to me... that if I can MOVE a snapped vertex along an edge, why don't I have the option to MERGE it when I press LMB???? WHYYYY?

Comment: It suppose to work, when you press Alt+M what option do you choose

Comment: yeah, sometimes it works. I am trying tinyMCE again, this seems to work sometimes too... but it is still not as convenient as a CAD program where you can connect edges as projections, having 90 degree angles and stuff... :/   http://glender.hybird.org/ this geometric tool looks awesome, but apparently it's just for an ancient blender