# How to add more edges in an object

Tags: modeling, vertices, unity

So, I'm an absolute beginner. I just started using Blender in order to create 3D objects to import into Unity, and right now I'm trying to create a lightning symbol. I started with the standard cube and I'm trying to reform it into a lightning, but I need to add more vertices to it and I don't know how. I've searched on Google and found a [way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/create-vertex-on-a-desired-part-of-an-edge) to add more vertices but it doesn't appear to be working (I'm probably doing something wrong). Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at these manual pages: [Basics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/index.html) and [Subdividing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/index.html), I also recommend the [official Blender YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSMOQeBJ2RAnuFungnQOxLg). It seems to me you are early enough in your learning that's the best way forward.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard,  but not particularly obvious either.

- Switch to edge select mode using the button at the bottom of the 3D view.
- Select the edges you want to add vertices to.
- Hit <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide. (*Not* Subdivide Smooth! Unless you want your new edge to be rounded, which doesn't sound like the case here.)
- (Optional) Switch back to vertex mode.

That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 0):

Select two or more vertices, then press <kbd>F</kbd> to create an edge.

Source: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/make_face_edge.html